# How to make a button work when touched using p5 code

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, code.org

I am making a game. In this a button goes to the next screen say from home screen to battle screen when clicked using a mouse.It works on computer/desktop but not on touchscreen device like mobile or tab.How do I make it work on touch screen devices ??? (It would be helpful if the answer is in p5 code, javascript or html). I can't afford to create button using HTML.

Currents I am using:

```
If(mousePressedOver(button)) {
   gamesSate = "BATTLE";

   battleScreen();
}
```

In above code `battleScreen();` I am calling a function in function `draw()` named battleScreen.

Comment: You should explain what is this `mousePressedOver()` function I don't think it is a built-in p5js function. Also I assume you create your button via the p5js `createButton()` function (note that this actually creates an HTML you just don't see it) so you should be able to use the [`touchStarted()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/touchStarted) function from p5js (Note that the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mousePressed) function might work on some mobile browsers too)

Comment: mousePressedOver is a function in editor.p5js. Will try create button but isn't there any code by which way to just write a few lines of code that make my game mobile friendly ???

Comment: mousePressedOver is not in p5 reference but it works and it's a part of p5js code

Answer (score 0):

I am a web developer. And `click` event works in all touch screen devices. And it works on every id, name, tag etc of html. you can try. Hope it will work
In javascript you can use `addEventListener`

```
document.getElementById("youId").addEventListener("click", function () {
    //your action
    // you can also use  document.getElementsByClassName, document.getElementsByName, document.getElementsByTagName etc in the place of getElementById
})
```

Comment: I am not that good in javascript. I know p5js.